# laravel 6 search query with multiple conditions

Tags: php, laravel

I have a search form with four fields of customer email, vendor name, status, and fromdate, todate,. My search filter is not working properly. I want if someone searches a lead with vendor name and status **Active** then it shows only leads of that vendor with status active status but here it shows a leads with both **Accept or Reject** also my date filter is not working so please help me. Please  guide me

**my controller code is**

```
    public function search(Request $request){
    $users = DB::table('users')->where('is_admin', Null)->get();

    $customer_email = $request->input('customer_email');
    $vendor_id = $request->input('vendor_id');
    $status = $request->input('lead_status');

    $leads = DB::table('leads')
        ->leftJoin('users', 'leads.vendor_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('leads.*', 'users.name')
        ->where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)
        ->orWhere('customer_email', $customer_email)
        ->orWhere('lead_status', $status)
        ->orWhere('leads.created_at', array($request->start_date, $request->end_date))
        ->orderBy('leads.created_at', 'DESC')->get();


    //dd($leads);

    return view('admin.view-leads', compact('leads'), compact('users'));

    
}
```

please help.
Thanks in advance

[query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzKxb.png)

Comment: Use laravel scopes instead of where conditions : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852704/laravel-search-query-with-multiple-conditions

Comment: perhaps you don't want to be using the "or wheres"? perhaps you need "and wheres" (regular `where`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty simple thing. Just follow the code below.

1. To get the users where `is_admin` is `null`.

   `$users = DB::table('users')->whereIsNull('is_admin')->get();`
2. To check if you are submitting a value for any filter.

   `if($request->filled('name_of_filter_input')){ //code goes here }`

So your query to filter records will go like.

```
$query = DB::table('leads')->query();
$query->leftJoin('users', 'leads.vendor_id', '=', 'users.id');
$query->select('leads.*', 'users.name');

if($request->filled('vendor_id')) {
    $query->where('vendor_id', $request->input('vendor_id'));
}

if($request->filled('customer_email')) {
    $query->where('customer_email', $request->input('customer_email'));
}

if($request->filled('lead_status')) {
   $query->orWhere('lead_status', $request->input('lead_status'));
}

if($request->filled('start_date') && $request->filled('end_date')) {
    $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('date(leads.created_at)'), [$request->input('start_date'), $request->input('end_date')]);
} 

$leads = $query->orderBy('leads.id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Further you can replace `DB::table('table_name')` syntax with respective model classes in case `query()` seems to be undefined function.

Wrap `leads.created_at` with `date()` function and ensure your date filter(s) has date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format if the created_at column is of type `timestamp`.

Comment: ankit sir, thanks for your answer now I get this message Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::query() how I solve this??????

Comment: yaa but it's not working sir...I do return $leads and it doesn't show any value

Comment: Just `dd($leads); ` to check of what it is having.

Comment: Yaa I do but it's blank

Comment: Please check your database for the particular filters if the data exists. Replace the `get()`  with `toSql()` in the end to get the raw sql and then run it in your phpmyadmin or any similar tool.

Comment: sir i use toSql() but it give this error message now Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel-6-CRM\resources\views\admin\view-leads.blade.php)

Comment: yes, now it gives "select `leads`.*, `users`.`name` from `leads` left join `users` on `leads`.`vendor_id` = `users`.`id` where `vendor_id` = ? and `customer_email` is null and `lead_status` = ? and `leads`.`created_at` between ? and ? order by `leads`.`created_at` desc  this query

Comment: Now run this query in your phpmyadmin. Replace the `?` with valid values.

Comment: it's not working it gives an error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`users`.`id` where `vendor_id` = 14 and `customer_email` is null and `lead_st...' at line 1

Comment: Paste your query here, what are you running in phpmyadmin.

Comment: select `leads`.*, `users`.`name` from `leads` left join `users` on `leads`.`vendor_id` = `users`.`id` where `vendor_id` = ? and `customer_email` is null and `lead_status` = ? and `leads`.`created_at` between ? and ? order by `leads`.`created_at` desc

Comment: select `leads`.*, `users`.`name` from `leads` left join `users` on `leads`.`vendor_id` = `users`.`id` where `vendor_id` = 3 and `customer_email` is null and `lead_status` = 0 order by `leads`.`created_at` desc still not getting sir

Comment: I upload an image also please see that to more clear

Answer (score 0):

you should write your query like as below

```
$leads = DB::table('leads')
        ->leftJoin('users', 'leads.vendor_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('leads.*', 'users.name')
        ->where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)
        ->when($customer_email, function($q,$customer_email){
             $q->where('customer_email', $customer_email);    
        })
        ->when($status, function($q,$status){
            $q->where('lead_status', $status);
        })
        ->where(function($q) use($request){
            if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date)){
                $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($request->start_date));
                $toDate= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($request->end_date));

                $q->where('leads.created_at', '>=', $fromDate)
                      ->where('leads.created_at', '<=', $toDate);
            }
        })
        ->orderBy('leads.created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

I updated my answer please look into it

Comment: it looks like you are trying to do what `when` does   https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @lagbox. I update my answer

Comment: @MrPerfect sir thanks for your answer but still I have the same issue....

Comment: if I select a vendor name with reject leads it gives an accept leads

Comment: make sure your $status variable value by using dump, because query return leads based on the status value